# Get screen resolution during boot up

Tags: screen, display-resolution

1. During Ubuntu 20.04 boot up, is any way to retrieve current screen resolution from my daemon process?
   Can we do this independent of X-window or Wayland graphical shell?
   Please advise me how.
2. In Ubuntu 20.04 X-window, XOpenDisplay() is failed during boot time. Do you know how why, and how to fix it?

Thank you for your time.
Thai

Comment: Thanks user535733, 
2. XOpenDisplay() is ok on Ubuntu 18 during boot time.  Only failed on Ubuntu 20.04.  
1. For independent of X-window and Wayland, is it any way I can monitor through /dev , /proc information?

Comment: Sorry. My question is: On Ubuntu 20.04, during boot up and just before user log-in. In my daemon C programming, can I retrieve the current screen resolution?  Thanks.

Comment: [Edit your Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1269056/edit). Don't bury the revised question in Comments, where almost nobody will see it. Comments get deleted (see, my older comments are gone!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly.
Maybe this will help.

from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks

GRUB can set the framebuffer for both GRUB itself and the kernel. The old vga= way is deprecated. The preferred method is editing /etc/default/grub as the following sample to set width (pixels) x height (pixels) x color depth:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Multiple resolutions can be specified, including the default auto, so it is recommended that you edit the line to resemble GRUB_GFXMODE=desired_resolution,fallback_such_as_1024x768,auto. For more information, refer to the GRUB gfxmode documentation. The gfxpayload property will make sure the kernel keeps the resolution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't want to set screen resolution. I want to programmatically (using C) retrieve the current screen resolution from my daemon during boot time before the user login.